# Limiting number of LEFT JOIN group

Tags: mysql, data-structures

With the following table:

```
SELECT i.*, GROUP_CONCAT(t.name) tagList
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = j.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

is there a way to limit the elements of tagList? Instead of giving me all the tags (30+ in some cases), could I just limit it to i.e. 5?

Comment: How about `LIMIT 5` at the end of your query

Comment: Which 5 would you want to select?

Comment: You need to define which one you want to limit. The whole result or the individual data for each table.

Comment: Er, it's the GROUP_CONCAT the OP wants to limit, not the number of rows!!??!?!?! @James consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: Hey thanks for your replies, as I mentioned, its the "tagList" that I want to limit. This is definied as a Group from the table "tags"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT i.*, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.name SEPARATOR ','), ',', 5) tagList
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN tag_rel AS tr ON (tr.item = j.id)
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON (t.id = tr.tag)
GROUP BY i.id 
ORDER BY i.id DESC
```

Just replace 5 with the number desired

Comment: Hopefully there is not a name with a `,` in it :)

Comment: Yes,there are some (reasonable) assumptions built into it.

Comment: Awesome! May I ask, is this preferable (performance?) to just getting to 5 first elements of "t.name" in php? What I was doing is $taglist = explode(',',$row['tagList']) to get an array, I could then just display the 5 first elements of the array. Is it the same?

Comment: In general,working on your data in sql is much faster than php. But for this case it doesn't really matter.Its just simpler to do it in sql(for me)